# Perl exported functions does not work

Tags: perl

Assuming I have this module:

```
package MyApp;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(msg);

sub import {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my ($package, $script) = caller;
    print "$package, $script\n";
}

sub msg {
    print "Hello msg\n";
}

1;
```

and used by this script App.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MyApp;
msg();
```

if I run this App.cgi I get this error:

```
undefined subroutine &main::msg in App.cgi at line 3
```

If I rename or remove the sub import in the package MyApp.pm it works fine.

So what is the problem with the import or how it should be used while exporting functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding Exporter's `import` method with one of your own that doesn't actually export anything, it just prints to stdout. Either don't do that (what's the point?) Or call `$class->export_to_level(1, @_)` to ensure that Exporter's stuff gets called. You need to use `export_to_level` and not `SUPER::import`, because your own `import` method adds a caller frame, and without being told otherwise, Exporter would export to the wrong place.

Comment: Added $class->export_to_level(1, @_) to the end of sub import worked. The point of the import in the MyApp package is I want to do some initializing stuff to the Package like setting script path etc.